# Rapid MVC desktop application framework in ruby

Tags: ruby, user-interface, desktop-application

Currently I am looking for a ruby desktop application framework. I have tried bowline. but it seems that dependencies are  outdated and I couldn't get it work... So is there any other framework available in ruby????

Answer (score 0):

GTK+ is one of popular GUI framework for X Window System. Actually it written on C language but it object-oriented and you can use wrapper languages and one of them is Ruby.

[www.gtk.org](http://www.gtk.org) — official site

[www.gtkforums.com](http://www.gtkforums.com) — GTK forum

[developer.gnome.org](http://developer.gnome.org) — information for GNOME developers, it has a lot usefull information about GTK.

Answer (score 0):

While no longer really active, Shoes by _why is quick to implement a rough GUI with, although not necessarily a great tool for a large complex GUI.

https://github.com/shoes/shoes